# Increment specific cell based on time and day

Tags: excel, vba

So im creating a spin button that connects to a macro. The button would increment a cell by 1 based on the hour of the day and what day of the week it is.

The code im using is:
UPDATE

```
Sub OneClick() 

strTime = Hour(Now()) 
Dim LWeekday As Integer 




LWeekday = Weekday(vbMonday) 


If strTime = 10 And LWeekday = 5 Then 
    Range("K4").Value = Range("K4") + 1 


ElseIf strTime = 11 And LWeekday = 5 Then 
    Range("K5").Value = Range("K5") + 1 




End If 


 'Select Case OneClickTest




 '
 '   Case strTime = 8 And LWeekday = 5
 '       Range("K2").Value = Range("K2") + 1


 '    Case strTime = 9 And LWeekday = 5
 '       Range("K3").Value = Range("K3") + 1




 'End Select

 End Sub
```

However im having two issues. The first is i dont think ive coded it right to get the hour of the day and the second is it only allows the spin control to increment, would i have to create a 2nd button to decrease the number by one?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thank you, I really need to learn how to format my coding on here. I'm sure its easy but I just haven't learned how to do it.

Comment: `    Sub OneClick()
strTime = Hour(Now())
Dim LWeekday As Integer


LWeekday = Weekday(vbMonday)



Select Case OneClickTest



    Case strTime = 8 And LWeekday = 5
        Range("K2").Value = Range("K2") + 1

    Case strTime = 9 And LWeekday = 5
        Range("K3").Value = Range("K3") + 1


End Select

End Sub
    `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your button is an ActiveX spin button, use the events related to the button, like `SpinButton1_SpinDown()` and `SpinButton1_SpinUp()`.

If the button is a forms control, then you will have a cell linked to the button where the click results in a change of value. Use that cell value in your code.

Comment: I don't think im quite explaining it right. Im not trying to increment one cell and one cell only im trying to increment a cell based on what hour of the day it is and what time it is. So for example, if its Thursday in the 1:00 hour then it will increment C5, if its the 2:00 hour then it will increment C6

Comment: I honestly think I might be making this more complicated than its needs to be. The hardest part of this is how do we declare the current hour of the day to a variable.

Comment: @Gehn47 If you just want to set a variable to be the current hour of the day just say `myVariable = Hour(Now())`

Comment: My post is not about what you do with the cells, it is about how you get info from the spin button, i.e. wether it was clicked for up or down. So, what type of spin button are you using? Form control or ActiveX??

Comment: I am using form control.

Comment: So, with a form control, when the up or down button is clicked, the value in the linked cell will change up or down. Write the cell value into a backup cell, then you can compare the two cells and work out if the up or the down was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final working code.

```
Sub OneClick()
strTime = Hour(Now()) 'grabs the current hour on a 24 hour rotation
Dim LWeekday As Integer

LWeekday = Weekday(Date, vbMonday) 'Set Monday as day 1



If strTime = 9 And LWeekday = 1 Then
 Range("C3").Value = Range("C3") + 1

ElseIf strTime = 10 And LWeekday = 1 Then
 Range("C4").Value = Range("C4") + 1

ElseIf strTime = 11 And LWeekday = 1 Then
 Range("C5").Value = Range("C5") + 1

ElseIf strTime = 12 And LWeekday = 1 Then
 Range("C6").Value = Range("C6") + 1

ElseIf strTime = 13 And LWeekday = 1 Then
 Range("C7").Value = Range("C7") + 1

ElseIf strTime = 14 And LWeekday = 1 Then
 Range("C7").Value = Range("C7") + 1

ElseIf strTime = 15 And LWeekday = 1 Then
 Range("C8").Value = Range("C8") + 1

ElseIf strTime = 16 And LWeekday = 1 Then
 Range("C9").Value = Range("C9") + 1

ElseIf strTime = 17 And LWeekday = 1 Then
 Range("C10").Value = Range("C10") + 1

ElseIf strTime = 18 And LWeekday = 1 Then
 Range("C11").Value = Range("C11") + 1




End If

End Sub
```